# Scikit-learn: MAE criterion using mean (rather than median)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

Scikit-learn's `absolute_error` criterion for decision trees and random forests (i.e., the MAE Criterion class: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/tree/_criterion.pyx) scales poorly compared to the default `squared_error` criterion.

See discussion here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9626

I'm working with a dataset that is too large to reasonably be able to use MAE, however, I'd like to do a little experimentation with MAE, or at least an approximation of it if possible.  Reading about how MAE works, I understand that it's based on using the median of individual leaves rather than the mean, which is what causes it to scale poorly compared to MSE.

Based on an incredibly shallow understanding of how the decision tree training process works, I would assume that I might be able to modify the MSE Criterion class to get an approximation to MAE.  Specifically, if MSE uses squared error, I would think that somewhere in there, I could just apply square roots to existing calculations to get absolute error.

For example, something like the following in the MSE class (see the first link):

```
for k in range(self.n_outputs):
    impurity_left[0] -= (self.sum_left[k] / self.weighted_n_left) ** 2.0
    impurity_right[0] -= (self.sum_right[k] / self.weighted_n_right) ** 2.0
```

might become:

```
for k in range(self.n_outputs):
    impurity_left[0] -= ((self.sum_left[k] / self.weighted_n_left) ** 2.0)**0.5
    impurity_right[0] -= ((self.sum_right[k] / self.weighted_n_right) ** 2.0)**0.5
```

However, all of my experimentation is leading to individual tree estimators that don't fit beyond one leaf and therefore predict the same value for all samples.

I'm just wondering whether this approach actually makes sense and, if so, what I would need to modify to make it work.

Comment: in the github discussion that you link, you can find an explanation of an implementation attempt: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9626#issuecomment-361085217 and also the link to the fork with the attempt: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/compare/main...mcgibbon:fast_mae does not seem easy (the author gave up due to some tests failing) and a bit more involved than your approach but could be a place to start

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few bits of confusion here. Firstly, with regard to scaling of MAE vs MSE, MSE can scale $O(n)$ whereas according to the Github issue you linked, MAE in scikit-learn scales $O(n^2)$, but MAE *could* be implemented to scale $O(n*log(n))$ (for details see the discussion about the PR which failed the unit tests in the link you provided). So if you want an efficient MAE, you may be able to implement one yourself and get that faster runtime.

With regard to your attempt/issues modifying mean squared error, I think you are a bit misguided. The error is squared to account for the fact that the calculated difference could be positive or negative, and error should be something monotonically increasing as you stray from 0 and a deviation of $x$ and $-x$ are equal. As a result, unfortunately you can not just "take the square root" - it will not work and can have unintuitive results.

As a side note, hopefully you will find [this](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9626#:%7E:text=PSA%2C%20users%20are%20encouraged%20to%20use%20HistGradientBoostingRegressor%20with%20loss%3D%27least_absolute_deviation%27%20which%20will%20be%20considerably%20faster) valuable (from the linked issue in your question):

> PSA, users are encouraged to use HistGradientBoostingRegressor with loss='least_absolute_deviation' which will be considerably faster

Comment: I might take a shot, but trying to write something fully from scratch would be a difficult undertaking.  I'm not sure I follow your second point.  The squared errors would be monotonic but so would the square roots of the squared errors.  Taking the square root of the squared error is equal to the absolute error.

Comment: Also, I tried HistGradientBoostingRegressor for this project and it was considerably worse than RandomForestRegressor with MSE.  Maybe that's an indication of how MAE would perform, but the reason I'm interested in this is that I tried RF with TransformedTargetRegressor with a custom transformer that took the square root of the Y values during fitting and squared the RF results during prediction and it gave some interesting results.  But after thinking about it, it gives something different than a true MAE, so I'd like to try the real thing if possible.